# How to drive nitinol (flexinol, muscle wire) through RPi

Tags: gpio

Is it possible to actuate muscle wire through Raspberry Pi ? This product expects ~200mA to revert to its original shape. If so, how would the circuit look like ? What resistors should I hookup ?

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12095

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'd recommend to put that question to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ to get better answers how to drive that wire. This is a little bit beyond hooking up some resistors (even if just a little that is).

Comment: Yea, its great that the datasheet has a typical application circuit.... noot. sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it requires is a switch of some kind to a voltage. It can be a Mosfet switch, triac, optocoupler (like in diagram) or a relay. Trigger the switch with a PIN.

Remember though, this stuff heats up (not sure how fast)! It has a ohms per meter specification too and a cool down period, depending on thickness. Its best to put a resistor on the negative side too to avoid short circuit by using Ohms law to calcalat e safe voltage drop. 5v to 2v for example.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKBM9my5eOA

Comment: thanks man, it looks simple enough. Is it possible to directly hook this wire to RPi without the optocoupler or is it too risky ?

Comment: No, I dont think the GPIo pin can handle that much current. You must always assume that conencitng something to PIN is not safe, that is why transistors are used for. You can find transistors anywher on any old PCB, search for the number on the transistor and you will get a docuement. for switching simple voltages almost anything can be used.